# How can we obtain $\sum_{l=1}^{m}(-1)^{l+1} \binom{m}{l} \equiv 1\pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

How can we obtain 
$$\sum_{l=1}^{m}(-1)^{l+1} \binom{m}{l} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} $$

Please give me an idea to obtain this.

Comment: not sure what you are asking exactly. for which values of $(m,p)$ the equality holds?

Comment: Idea: forget about $p$ and try to compute $$\sum_{l = 0}^{m} (-1)^l \binom{m}{l}\,.$$

Comment: expand $(1-1)^m=0$ using the binomial theorem

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you so much!